# Youtube service in Delphi

Tags: delphi, youtube

How to upload a video to youtube in Delphi? Examples, hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the [YouTube API](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/youtube/overview.html) and the [Data API Protocol – Direct Uploading](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_direct_uploading.html).